# How can I debug Blazor WebAssembly ASP.NET Core hosted when using Docker or Docker Compose?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

Blazor WebAssembly ASP.NET Core hosted project does not copy the client project `wwwroot` to the output folder of server project when configuration is `Debug` or `Release`, except I use `Publish`.

This means it can not work properly for `docker-compose` debugging or release.

if you run the docker or compose project, then access `http://localhost` you will get 404 not found.
But if you access `http://localhost/controller` it works well.

more details please read this: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20613

So my question is how to debug it?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Mojack No, I give up.